# How to import ROS project C++ file into QT-Creator and compile them?

Tags: ros, c++, compile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to import my ROS project into Qt-Creator for compiling and having some gui and so on, so I've searched so much about it on th net but I couldn't find a specific answer for this question.
consider that I want to import the ROS main tutorial on ROS site into QT-Creator, for instance I want to compile my client C++ node in Qt-Creator with out compiling it in terminal window, so is there any way ?
I need more visual interface for Coding than linux text editor.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73468/how-to-import-ros-project-c++-file-into-qt-creator-and-compile-them?/) by [SeiedMilad](https://answers.ros.org/users/5824/seiedmilad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's actually fairly easy to use QtCreator with ROS (I do it myself). [This](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs) is a link that explains in more detail.

Briefly, you have to launch **qtcreator** from the terminal so that the program is aware of your environment variables (`$PATH`, `$PYTHONPATH` and so on...)

Once you've done that, go to **File**->**Open Project** and navigate to the `CMakeLists.txt` of your project (if you're using catkin that'd be `/path/to/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt`). QtCreator will then ask you to choose a build directory. Simply select the build directory inside the package (or `/path/to/catkin_ws/build`/ if using catkin). Finally tell QtCreator to run CMake, and voilà you're done!

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2013-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/3571/redheli/) on 2013-08-25**:
Thanks Miguel, it works!

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2013-12-12**:
well,how to import ROS project python file into QT-Creator and compile them??

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-08-08**:
When setting things up this way the build system only creates a **build** directory, not a **devel** directory. I guess this is because catkin is not called, only CMake is, no? So what is the good practise? Work in qtcreator and then compile using catkin in a separate terminal?

**Comment by [Anurag VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/29692/anurag-vv/) on 2018-06-14**:
I launch qtcreator from sourced terminal but still qtcreator cannot find maky catkin packages like cv_bridge, rosconsoleConfig ect. But i can build the package from terminal through catkin_make.. How is terminal able to find the packages where qtcreator is failing?